# Twitter bootstrap: How can I open a modal window on input focus?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 and I want to open a modal window when the user focus on a input box. How can i do that?

```
<form>

<input type="text"  id="openmodalOnfocus" data-toggle="modal" data-target="myModal">

</form>

<div class="modal hide" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="row">
          <div class=" col-md-4">
            lorem i[p sum on left
         </div>

          <div class=" col-md-4">
            lorem ipsom on right
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data-toggle` attribute cannot be used to automatically open the dialog box in your specific scenario via Bootstrap. The good news is that it is quite easy to achieve that in another way.

First, you can remove the `data-*` attributes from your text box as they will not be of use here; then, you can open the dialog box on focus by adding the following javascript code (using jQuery):

```
$(function() {
    $('#myModal').focus(function() {
        $(this).modal('show');
    });
});
```